# Sum of sine data fitting with mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, curve-fitting, trigonometry

Hy everyones,

I've a little problem with a mathematica script which I need for fitting data points with a sum of 3 sine functions :

```
fit = NonlinearModelFit[Data,a1*Sin[b1*x + c1] + a2*Sin[b2*x + c2] + a3*Sin[b3*x + c3], {a1, b1,c1, a2, b2, c2, a3, b3, c3}, x]
```

I get this error :

```
NonlinearModelFit::cvmit: Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100 iterations
```

I've tried with different starting values and with MaxIteration set to 10.000...
Maybe it's not the right way to do this kind of fitting. Does anyone have an idea about this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you joint your data to the question ? Without data one cannot see where is the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your data is too bad, but it works nicely with a good sample:

```
data = Table[{x, Sin[ x + .3] + 2 Sin[1.2 x] + 3 Sin[1.5 x + .5]}, 
             {x, .01,  8 Pi, .001}];
fit = NonlinearModelFit[data, 
          a1*Sin[b1*x + c1] + a2*Sin[b2*x + c2] + a3*Sin[b3*x + c3], 
          {a1, b1, c1, a2, b2, c2, a3, b3, c3}, x]

Show[ListPlot[data], Plot[fit[x], {x, 0, 8 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Red], Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is I can't increase the number of data... each point is taking 3 days to compute on 32 CPU... :D (I've 20 data points)

any other ideas?

Comment: @B.jour With 20 data points and nine free parameters I think you're in deep trouble :)